# How to change the div with repect to the menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical menu.When I click on the first menu i want to show the corresponding div on right side.Two div is possible through it.But cannot do others.How can I do this?
script is

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").hide();
    $("#master").click(function(){
        $("#leftpanel").show();
        $(".box1").show();
    });
    $("#country").click(function(){
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".box1").show();
    });
    $("#currency").click(function(){
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".box2").show();
    });
    $("#city").click(function(){
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".box3").show();
    });
    $("#EmissionsCountry").click(function(){
        $(".box4").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });
    $("#EmissionsFuel").click(function(){
        $(".box5").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });
    $("#IfcIndustrySector").click(function(){
        $(".box6").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });
    $("#ReTechnologyType").click(function(){
        $(".box7").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });
    $("#Unit").click(function(){
        $(".box8").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });
    $("#Energy").click(function(){
        $(".box9").show();
        $(".box").hide();
    });

});
```

Html is

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftpanel">
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1" id="country"> Country</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1" id="currency"> Currency</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> City</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> EmissionsCountry</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> EmissionsFuel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> IfcIndustrySector</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> ReTechnologyType</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> Unit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="menu1"> Energy</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imagediv">
                <div class="image"><img src="arrow.gif"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightpanel">
        <div class="box1 box" id="country">
            country
        </div>
        <div class="box2 box" id="currency">
            currency
        </div>
        <div class="box3 box" id="city">
            city
        </div>
        <div class="box4 box" id="EmissionsCountry">
            EmissionsCountry
        </div>
        <div class="box5 box" id="EmissionsFuel">
            EmissionsFuel
        </div>
        <div class="box6 box" id="IfcIndustrySector">
            IfcIndustrySector
        </div>
        <div class="box7 box" id="ReTechnologyType">
            ReTechnologyType
        </div>
        <div class="box8 box" id="Unit">
            Unit
        </div>
        <div class="box9 box" id="Energy">
            Energy
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the demo from [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uu9ws/)

Comment: As a side note `id` should be unique. In your HTML you have a lot of `<div id="menu1">`

Comment: sorry.. i am forgot to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit and added `data-box` so you know which `.box` you show.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/uu9ws/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".box").hide();
    $('.menu1').click(function () {
        var boxid = $(this).data('box');
        $('.box').hide();
        $('.box' + boxid).show();
    });
});
```

I think this will simplify your script a lot and make it more easier to change.

The actuall problem in you HTML is that you don't have `IDs` assigned to `<a>`. You only have `IDs` for the first 2 menu elements and in your script you use

```
.show(); // this will show the box you need
.hide(); // but then you hide all the boxes 
         //(even the one you need because it has the class .box)

//Instead use

.hide(); // hide all the boxes
.show(); // show the one you need
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/uu9ws/2/) with your code <-- added `IDs` and corrected script `show/hide`

Comment: here is a horizontal menu.The last menu 'Admin' contains two other child menu 'master' and 'usermanagement'.When I click on the master the left panel is shown.But its not worked..

Comment: can you also include `DisplayChild();` and `HideChild();` in the fiddle. I can't use the dropdown otherwise.

Comment: what doesn't work? seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/uu9ws/5/ (note I changed the display/hide functions because they were not loading)

Comment: the problem is with when you select the 'home' menu after selecting 'master', you can see the leftpanel comes on each menu

Comment: [lets chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29292/room-for-spokey-and-agent1)

Answer (score 0):

If youre going to do it this way(by giving divs multiple class names) you should have your .hide functions ALWAYS first in the javascript above, and your .show ALWAYS second.  Whats happening is you're showing all elements with a class name of **box4**, but then hiding all the elements with a class name of **box**, which includes box4 and the other later divs, so you show it, but then make it hide RIGHT after.

Hope this helps

Comment: Try closing your browser, or clearing your cache - it could be a javascript caching problem.

Also, you should probably use the id instead of the class to show, that way things will be less confusing.  Instead of using $(".box5").show();, try, $("#EmissionsFuel").show()

That will guarantee that youre targeting that particular div only.  You should keep your hide() first before the show though still, because youd still hide the div after showing it.